# c: default values for repeated fields with nanopb (protobuf)

Tags: c, protocol-buffers, nanopb

I am trying to create a message with a repeated field which has some default values.
I'm starting slow, with a simple int repeated (my final goal is a repeated message which all fields are have some value default)

so, to start my proto is:

```
syntax = "proto2"
import "google/protobuf/descriptor.proto";
import "nanopb.proto";

message MyDefault {
  repeated int32 default = 1 [(nanopb).max_count = 3];
}

extend google.protobuf.FieldOptions {
  optional MyDefault my_default = 1234;
}

message M {
  repeated int32 x = 1 [(my_default) = {default: [1, 2, 3]}, (nanopb).max_count = 3];
}
```

protobuf is compiled, but no trace to my default values.

Comment: Are you using Proto2 or Proto3? Can you add this to your example? From the usage of optinal I assume you are using Proto2. That is good as in Proto3 default values are not supported, they are always set to zero or false.

Comment: yes, I'm using proto2 since 3 doesn't support default, as you mentioned... (will add to my question)

Comment: I've searched through the documentation and unit tests of nanopb but at this moment I can not find an awnser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are no default values for repeated fields in nanopb currently. As far as I know, they don't exist in other protobuf implementations either.

Some other protobuf libraries do provide access to custom field options, but nanopb currently does not.